# Timeout or Strategy Question for parsing huge XML-Files in Angular

Tags: json, angular, timeout

I´m new on Angular and try to parse Adobe IDML (XML) files for showing them up in a browser. Let me explain that:

There is the following XML-Structure ("->" means gives info about next line):

```
IDML (designmap.xml) ->
    Spread (spread_xy.xml) ->
        Page ->
            TextFrames ->
                Story
            Rectangle ->
                Image
```

I have written a backend that translates these files in JSON-Arrays and I load these JSON-Arrays via HTTP. So far so good.

The following is my corresponding IDML-Service in the Frontend:

```
export class IdmlService {
  apiUrl = environment.backendApi + 'idml/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  renderSpread(currentFolder, currentSpreadId): Observable<HttpResponse<any[]>> {
    return this.http.get<MenuItem[]>(
      this.apiUrl + currentFolder + '?spreadId=' + currentSpreadId, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
        retry(3)
      );
  }
}
```

I call "renderSpread"-method in my publicationComponent like this:

```
  renderPublication(currentFolder: String, currentSpreadId: String): void {
    this.idmlService.renderSpread(currentFolder, currentSpreadId)
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.currentSpreadJson = resp.body;
        // console.log(this.currentSpreadJson);
      });
  }
```

and bind the "currentSpreadJson" to the child component called spreadComponent in the template:

```
<div class="publication">
    <app-spread [currentSpreadJson]="currentSpreadJson"></app-spread>
</div>
```

In the spreadComponent I construct my currentSpread and bind the necessary rest of JSON via "currentElementsJson" to the next child elementsComponent like this:

```
@Input() currentSpreadJson: any;
currentSpread: Spread;
currentElementsJson: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => { // THE MAIN PROBLEM
      this.render();
    }, 3000);
  }

  render(): void {
    this.currentSpread = {
      id: this.currentSpreadJson.idPkg_Spread.Spread['Self'],
      [...some other vars...]
    };

    [...doing some stuff...]

    this.currentElementsJson = this.currentSpreadJson.idPkg_Spread.Spread;
  }
```

Here´s the template:

```
<div id="{{currentSpread.id}}" class="spread box_shadow" [ngStyle]="{'width': currentSpread.width + 'px', 'height': currentSpread.height + 'px'}">
    <app-page [currentSpreadJson]="currentSpreadJson"></app-page>
    <app-element [currentElementsJson]="currentElementsJson"></app-element> // <-- here
</div>
```

So here my question: Such an IDML could become very huge. This strategy goes deeper in the XML-Tree and the problem is that I always need to do a timeout onInit. I tried some other lifecycles like ngAfterViewInit and so on, but I think the upper strategy is not the thing I need for my project. I heared about "async await"-functions, but I don´t really know how to implement that in this context and I´m not sure if this is the solution. It would be nice if somebody could give me a hint. Thank you.

Regards, Dominik

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me now. I changed this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => { // THE MAIN PROBLEM
      this.render();
    }, 3000);
  }
```

to that:

```
ngAfterContentChecked() {
      this.render();
  }
```

Now the nested components wait until the Content is available.

Regards